# What would you like to see in a Philosophy.SE site theme?

Tags: discussion, community, design

Not that I think graduation is on the immediate horizon, but I thought it might not be the worst idea to start a conversation about interesting design elements for a post-graduation theme. Also interesting in this context might be short phrases or expressions that we might be able to use as a community/domain name.

What would you like to see in a Philosophy.SE site theme? What visual elements (colors, shapes, metaphors) do you think might help vividly express the rich uniqueness of our community?

Comment: Parchment background and Aquiline font! ;)

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest something hinting at the Greek origins of philosophy -- a carved from marble look, perhaps...

Comment: Something similar to the TeX.SE banner would be kind of nice. They have a bunch of typeset symbols in their banner. If we had something similar but emphasizing themes in philosophy that could be nice. Some logical formalism (quantifiers?), some key ancient greek words (arete, episteme, etc.). I like the blue, maybe stick with that for the general color scheme, but maybe incorporate the marbling or something else to add a bit more flair.

Comment: I could do with shiny new badges in the shape of, say, chess figures. Or maybe tiny little books. Or tiny columns? Hard to think of anything that's still recognisable that small and that fits the topic.

Comment: A brain somewhere would be nice. The *Thinker* could also be a nice touch. The badges could be stars of light (the almost universal symbol of understanding).

Comment: Split right down the middle for a yin and yang feel. Or perhaps a three-way split—black, white, and a large grey area :|

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our Community Managers from earlier today: [Custom Philosophy SE design and logo - Information gathering](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5314/31765) :)

Comment: Update: [Your new site design is live!](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5365/31765)