# Your new site design is live!

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see, the new design just went live! At this point, we are done with major revisions to the design (although you can still report CSS/styling bugs by starting a new post and tagging it with [design](/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)). Thank you for your [valuable design feedback](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5332/site-design-and-logo-draft) and for your patience while we got this out for you.

We really hope you like the design! Thanks so much to SCoSO for his work on this!

Comment: Thanks, but I find the old sans serif font, which is used by almost all of the other stackexchange sites, more readable than the new serif font.

Comment: The other issue is that the tags on the homepage have these really strong, dark blue borders around them that make them stand out more than the question itself. Other stackexchange sites will universally have pale, unobtrusive borders around the tags so they don't stand out. e.g. check out [english](http://english.stackexchange.com), [politics](http://politics.stackexchange.com), [board games](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com), [graphic design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com), [physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: It's awful, thanks for asking. *Jarring* is the word that comes to mind.

Comment: Sans serif font, lighter shade of blue for tags, and it's perfect.

Comment: I have to admit that I'm a bit confused. It seemed like there was universal approval for the design when we previewed it a while back, so it's somewhat difficult for us to make changes at this point. Not impossible but y'all had two months to give us this feedback and no one pointed any of this out.

Comment: @Catija I wasn't aware of the draft until the change went live. So why didn't someone else mention it? I can only speculate that the draft was presented as an inline png image, which is scaled down and presented in a different context than the actual site, so it's harder to get a "general impression" from the standpoint of a user of the site. Also the tag colors in the draft were a mix of gray and blue rather than just blue.

Comment: @causative I understand that the images in the post appeared smaller, but clicking on them expands them to high-resolution images that actually appear to be around 200% of my current page size. Comparing them side-by-side, the primary tags appear identical in the before and after. The grey tags you can see in the image are "meta" tags that don't actually apply on main sites, only here on meta. I understand this may have caused some confusion and I'll see what we can do to avoid that in the future.

Comment: I think that serif fonts in general have lower readability at small (pixel) sizes compared to sans-serif of the same size. The letters are too small to be useable with serif fonts. --- I also agree that the dark blue tags stand out too much.

Comment: I know I'm terribly late to the party, but those images are just not representative of the fonts used. They have nice high resolution and smoothing. But the "comment" font in actual use is _so much_ smaller and granier. Exactly the reason why serif fonts are not recommended for small font sizes. I've put the sample image next to the same text in a comment and the difference is stark, *even when scaled to the same size*. Maybe that's why there weren't much responses to the design, because it looked much better in high resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Most aspects seem very nice to me, and many thanks to the team for the work! But **is there any chance of getting the Φ in the masthead “PHILΦSOPHY” changed?**

This is the one criticism which was mentioned as [feedback on the draft](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5332/site-design-and-logo-draft), by Wrzlprmft in comments (albeit rather politely, which I fear led to its getting overlooked).  It’s really jarring for anyone who reads Greek — Φ isn’t some kind of decorative O, it’s a totally different letter, roughly equivalent to English *PH*.  (Which is why the standalone Φ/φ is a great logo: to a broad audience it evokes classical Greek, but for those in the know, it’s also the initial letter of *philosophy*.)  This is like if [Russian Language stackexchange](https://russian.stackexchange.com) had ЯUSSIAИ in its masthead.

To most people seriously interested in philosophy, this pretty clearly stands out as designed/chosen by people who don’t know the field well or care about getting things right.  **It’s not a great first impression for the site to give.**

[I realise I’m a little late here, and I’m not a power user on this site by any means.  But these posts seem to have had very little visibility — currently just 189 views on this announcement and 210 on the draft feedback post — so I hope the admins aren’t considering the feedback window totally closed.]

Comment: Thank you for writing this so well. I completely agree that using the letter Φ instead of O is extremely disturbing. I cannot help myself, I always see the title as **PHILFSOPHY** :( --- Note: I am just a passive occasional user of this site so I had almost no chance of noticing the new design being prepared.