# high-end font and design

Tags: discussion, design

Recently, the font of this site has changed to a more advanced level, and the logo seems to have changed as well. Who is changing this?

The font:
[image]

Comment: They changed it. Personally I preferred the way it was before.

Comment: it's terrible, but this should belong in meta.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Philosophy SE design and logo - Information gathering](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5314/custom-philosophy-se-design-and-logo-information-gathering)

Comment: The change going live was announced in this post: [Your new site design is live!](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5365/9322) You will find more specific criticism of the change there. --- I also do not like the font but the worse thing is the use of the letter Phi instead of O in the logo.

Answer (score 3):

You guys had two and a half months to give feedback.

If you did never care to look into meta, saying how bad the decisions made are is a bit cheap. After all, you had every opportunity to participate in the process *before* it went online.

Comment: What percentage of users do anything with meta? It was not advertised where the users are. If the staff actually wanted feedback they should have done a tentative live rollout to the main site. Which they should have done anyway since you can't get the same impression from an image at the wrong scale as you can get from actually using the design. Besides, it's the graphic designer's job to produce something that looks good.

Comment: @causative It was featured, ie. everybody had it on their main site. Nobody cared to even mention the font.